# packaging an extension for a webapp

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven, packaging

I have a j2ee-webapp which can be extended by different modules (plugins). These modules contain jsp's as well as .class and resource files.

What is the best way to package such a module ?

Comment: Are you using a thing like OSGI ? What do you expect as a structure to use such a module?

Comment: No, the webapp has a maven-webapp structure. Maybe the module should look similar to this.

Comment: Ok means a simple web-app structure so you should handle it as a usual maven-web-app build.

Comment: But it is only a module which depends on the core app. So it should not be possible to deploy this module as standalone app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at war overlays:
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html